# Data manipulation in R - creating a new data frame from an existing one

Tags: r

I have the below data frame in R

```
id <- c(112, 112,112)
case <- c("up","down","worse")
c1 <- c(0.12,0.24,0.09)
c2 <- c(0.11,0.14,0.06)
c3 <- c(0.15,0.34,0.04)
c4 <- c(0.16,0.44,0.03)
c5 <- c(0.17,0.94,0.01)
df3 <- data.frame(id,case,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
```

I am trying to create a new data frame with column names as id, case, value_in_period, and period
For each id, the period will have values from 0-9. The value_in_period column will take values of c1,c2,c3,c4, and c5 from periods 0-5 and the rest of the values will be 0. A sample of desired output is attached below

[image]

I tried using inner join and transpose, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We reshape to 'long' format and then use `complete` to expand the data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- df3 %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = c1:c5, names_to = NULL, 
      values_to = 'value_in_period') %>% 
   group_by(id, case = factor(case, levels = unique(case))) %>% 
  mutate(period = row_number()-1) %>%
  complete(period = 0:9, fill = list(value_in_period = 0)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  relocate(period, .after = 'value_in_period')
```

-output

```
> as.data.frame(out)
    id  case value_in_period period
1  112    up            0.12      0
2  112    up            0.11      1
3  112    up            0.15      2
4  112    up            0.16      3
5  112    up            0.17      4
6  112    up            0.00      5
7  112    up            0.00      6
8  112    up            0.00      7
9  112    up            0.00      8
10 112    up            0.00      9
11 112  down            0.24      0
12 112  down            0.14      1
13 112  down            0.34      2
14 112  down            0.44      3
15 112  down            0.94      4
16 112  down            0.00      5
17 112  down            0.00      6
18 112  down            0.00      7
19 112  down            0.00      8
20 112  down            0.00      9
21 112 worse            0.09      0
22 112 worse            0.06      1
23 112 worse            0.04      2
24 112 worse            0.03      3
25 112 worse            0.01      4
26 112 worse            0.00      5
27 112 worse            0.00      6
28 112 worse            0.00      7
29 112 worse            0.00      8
30 112 worse            0.00      9
```

Comment: what does the following line do ? cols = matches('^c\\d+$'). I get an error Error: `cols` must select at least one column.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred

Comment: @narayanan_pr it is selecting the columns c1 to c5 i.e. `\\d+` implies one or more digits.  Not sure whether your error is related to any older version of package or not

Comment: @narayanan_pr you can also use `cols = c1:c5`